# How to find match a sentence in a file in linux and edit a part of it

Tags: python, linux, sed, grep

I want to search a file in linux for a particular sentence and then edit it as per my need (In my case I want to edit the end of the sentence after "`=`" symbol) .. any help ?

For e.g. I want to search this line in a file:

```
[some.random.line]=100
```

and want to replace `100` with `1` .. any clue ?

Comment: there are many ways to do that. At least, show that particular sentence

Comment: Use sed in linux.

Comment: Too vague. Some file type e.g. config file , can be modify using a proper manipulation tools.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -i -e 's/=.*$/=1/' infile
```

This will replace anything following the first `"="` sign with `"1"`, for all lines of the input file. The `-i` option tells `sed` to update the file in place. You can also create a backup of the original file:

```
$ sed --in-place=.bak -e 's/=.*$/=1/' infile
```

Not all versions of `sed` support in place modification, if that's the case you can write to a temp file, and then replace the original file:

```
$ sed -e 's/=.*$/=1/' infile >outfile && mv outfile infile
```

The output is directed to a second file. If the `sed` command is successful the original input file will be overwritten.